# Helping or Help?

Tags: grammar

Could the word "help" be used instead of "helping" in this sentence? Would the meaning be the same either way?

> "Money will also go to helping the pink iguana and the Floreana tortoise."

This is where I found the sentence:
https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2021/may/18/leonardo-dicaprio-pledges-43m-to-restore-the-galapagos-islands

I think both work since helping is in the future continuous form and is talking about money that will be used in the future and continue for an expected length of time. Help is a verb that can also be used for the future when used with "will"(Example: He will help...).

[https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-words-help-and-helping-in-the-English-language-Arent-they-both-nouns#:~:text=%E2%80%9CHelp%E2%80%9D%20is%20both%20a%20noun,meaning%20a%20serving%20of%20food.&text=We%20don't%20use%20the,we%20use%20%E2%80%9Chelp%E2%80%9D%20instead](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-words-help-and-helping-in-the-English-language-Arent-they-both-nouns#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CHelp%E2%80%9D%20is%20both%20a%20noun,meaning%20a%20serving%20of%20food.&text=We%20don%27t%20use%20the,we%20use%20%E2%80%9Chelp%E2%80%9D%20instead).

Comment: Yes; in fact, an infinitive like _help_ would be more normal than a gerund like _helping_ here.